# (angular 2) configuring node.js routes to return index.html with additional JSON

Tags: json, node.js, angular, mean-stack

Following an angular2 course, I ended up with the following backend node.js server code snippet, when I try to GET contests from frontend:

```
router.get('/', function(req,res,next) {   // actually /contests/
Contest.find()
  .populate('user', 'firstName')
  .exec(function(err, docs) {
  if (err) {
  return res.status(404).json({
    title: 'Error !',
    error: err
  });
  }
  res.status(200).json({
    message: 'Success',
    obj: docs
  });
  });
});
```

Which works fine when I reach it from inside my app, but if I try to access it by simply typing the url: .../contests/ and hitting enter, I only receive the JSON objects displayed on the page, which isn't what I intend to do with a normal app.

What I want to do is return the proper page ( = render index.html file for all pages (angular2 SPA)), but also to have some JSON data attached to the response, which I could access in the frontend. Is there a way to achieve that? Something like:

```
  res.render('index', {message: 'Success', obj: docs});  // Not working
```

instead of just

```
res.json({ ... })
```

For routes which don't contain GETs that return JSON, everything works.

I don't understand if the code snippet is architecturally wrong or if I'm just stupid, as I can't find any info on this while googling. I'm relatively new to node.js.

Any help, input or pointers would be appreciated !

Answer (score 0):

I realize now it's unnecessary to access the contests this way. I solved it by simply forwarding all such GETs to my API endpoint.